# DLL trust issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis, paypal

I am working on a project which uses two .dll files related to paypal. It appears that those two .dll s have trust issues as my project is working fine in asp.net development servers and also in IIS but whenever my project is run on hosting server I am getting the error:

```
That assembly doesn't allow partially trusted callers
```

The hosting server is appeared to be on medium trust level and I think, which may be wrong, those two .dll files have full trust enabled and that's why I am getting that error.

I have tried many processes which I've found on stackoverflow and asp.net forum but those didn't yield any success and I am still getting the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See this: http://www.smith-consulting.com/Forums/forumid/13/threadid/166/scope/posts.aspx ... and this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332201/paypal-asp-net-medium-trust ... They are probably already installed into the GAC but don't have the allowed partially trusted callers attribute...which is why you are getting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit my head many times against this problem in the past.

First of all, see if you're targeting net framework 2.0 up to 3.5 or 4.0 up to 4.5.

In the former case you can have that kind of problem, and to my experience there were three possible approaches:

- Get, if available, the sources of the desired third party components and recompile them using a strong name
- Use an alternative component that provides the same functionality but doesn't have issues on medium trust
- Get a hosting service that runs in full trust (which is, in my opinion, the best choice)

In the latter (.Net 4.0+) you shouldn't be experiencing this problem since it was changed how trust in handled on libraries.